# Host name for a standalone docker container

Tags: docker, matrix-synapse

I have a docker setup made up of a compose file with 2 services and one app running in a standalone container.

My compose file has this structure

```
version: '3'

services:

  synapse:
    image: docker.io/matrixdotorg/synapse:latest
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8008:8008
  db:
    image: docker.io/postgres:12-alpine
    # other commandds
```

When I do `docker-compose up` a default network called `synapse_default`. And the synapse service is able to connect to the `db` using `db` as host. That is my postgres URL looks like this `postgres://synapse:synapse@db/postgres`. You'll notice the host name is `db` and this works because they're been run in the same docker network.

Now I have a standalone application in another container I run with `docker run --network=synapse_default` and this app is able to connect to the synapse and db services using the service names as host addresses.

My problem now is to have the synapse service talk to standalone application. Since this standalone application was not part of the compose file, it does not have a service name hence I'm not sure what to specify as the host for the `synapse` service to be able to reach the standalone application.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the name of your 'standalone application' with `docker ps`:

```
~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID     CREATED          STATUS          NAMES
205f1583e0a0     42 seconds ago   Up 40 seconds   foo
```

`foo` in the example above is the name you can use. You can also use `205f1583e0a0` (CONTAINER ID) if you find it convenient. If you wish to use a specific name (like `foo` in the example), you have to run the standalone application with `--name` argument:

```
docker run --name=foo ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by specifying `--hostname` when running my standalone container.

I'm only keep this question open because I already have one response but this was a weak question as I failed to do proper research. A quick `docker run --help` provided me with the answer I needed.